# Wildcard in rename and robocopy command into batch file

Tags: windows, batch, robocopy, batch-rename

What I am attempting to do is automate some work I do daily. What I would like to happen is a prompt saying What is your name? Then use that answer as a variable to be used in different commands like REN and ROBOCOPY. I am currently doing the following.

```
set /p var1="What is your Name?"
cd C:\ProgramData\filepath\Users\
IF exist var1(brk_file) (
gotto :renamed)
else
(goto :repair)
:Repair
REN "var1\current" "current.old"
ROBOCOPY "var1\backup" "current" /e
```

Now, their name will always be used in the folder name, but it could include a version number or MD or something else. For instance my answer would be "Cam" but my folder I am wanting to rename and copy is "CamV10"

So I would like something like

```
if exist *var1*(brk_file) (
goto :renamed)
else
(goto :repair)
:repair
REN "*var1*\current" "current.old"
ROBOCOPY "*var1*\backup" "current" /e
```

This is not working for me, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If `var1` in your post is supposed to be the variable, it should be surrounded by percent-signs: `%var1%` and not with asterisks. But the code is a bit unclear and has other typos, too, so please do edit the question with the actual code that works (can be executed without errors).

Comment: For example, `IF exist var1(brk_file)` (with or without the asterisks) doesn't look like something that matches the [`IF` command syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

Comment: Adding the *%Var1%* has resolved it, thank you! I completely spaced the %. So now I am able to test that section and echo true.

    set /p var1="What is your Name?"
    cd C:\ProgramData\filepath\Users\
    IF exist *%var1%*(brk_file) echo true

Comment: What is `(brk_file)`? If it's a string and part of the `var1`, you have to escape `(` and `)` like ^(brk_file^) Or you could probably enclose in double quotes like `IF exist "var1(brk_file)"` but not sure. Anyway this kind of symbol in files path are never good.

Answer (score 0):

This is an XY problem. To solve Y, you create a second problem called X and so on. While it easier to ask whether there is not already a solution for Y.

Which is the case. This is called **[Environment Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values)**.
In your case you are seeking for the user variable.

Type `set` in the cmd you will understand what I mean.

Then type `@echo My username is: %USERNAME% and my home is: %USERPROFILE%`.
which will return:

```
 My username is: John and my home is: C:\Users\John
```

Anyway many mistakes in your code. You have to read `IF /?` because `ELSE` statement have to be in the same line of `IF` unless you use `)` then it should be written in one line like `) ELSE (`

Another thing: 
What is `(brk_file)`?

If it's a string and part of the `var1`, you have to escape `(` and `)` like

```
IF exist %var1%^(brk_file^)
```

or may you could probably enclose in double quotes like

```
IF exist "%var1%(brk_file)"
```

but honestly I am not sure.
Anyway this kind of symbol in files path are never good

Comment: My need for this file was to repair voice files associated to Nuance. They "corrupt" in 2 ways.
The first would be c:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaurallySpeaking*\Users\Camv10\current -folder craps out for some reason, which the fix is to delete "Current" and make a copy of the back up file and name it current.

Comment: And the second is when Nuance goes to overwrite the backup folder with the current folder and fails for some reason. What it will do is Keep the existing working folder and add (DGN_RENAMED) so camv10(DGN_RENAMED) and then it will dump the the progress of the backup to a folder named camv10 in my case so you must delete the broken camv10 folder then rename the camv10(DGN_RENAMED back to just camv10.

Both of these situations come up often, so here is what I cam up with

Comment: SET/p var1="What is the providers name?"%
CD c:\PrgmDta\Nuance\NatSpeaking*\Users\
IF EXIST **%var1%**(DGN_RENAMED) (
GOTO :Renamed)
ELSE
(GOTO :Repair)
:Renamed
CD c:\PrgrmDta\Nuance\NatSpeaking*\Users\*%var1%*
for %%* in (.) do set var2=%%~nx*
CD c:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking*\Users\***(DGN_RENAMED) 
for %%* in (.) do set var3=%%~nx*
CD c:\PrgrmData\Nuance\NatSpeaking*\Users\
RMDIR /S /Q %var2%
SET var4=%Var3:~0,-13%
rename %var3% %var4%
GOTO eof
:Repair
CD c:\PrgrmDta\Nuance\NatSpeaking*\Users\*%var1%*
REN "current" "current.old"
ROBOCOPY "backup" "current" /e